# Spring boot, tomcat, rest api 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, tomcat, war

I am using Kotlin + Gradle and trying to build a war file to deploy on Tomcat. My application is from the https://start.spring.io plus a simple controller and build the war file using `./gradlew bootWar`

```
@SpringBootApplication
class ServletInitializer : SpringBootServletInitializer() {

    override fun configure(application: SpringApplicationBuilder): SpringApplicationBuilder {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication::class.java)
    }

}

@RestController
class TomcatController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun sayHello(): Collection<String> {
        return IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .mapToObj { i: Int -> "Hello number $i" }
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    }
}
```

when I try to access it I get

```
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

I am super stuck. What am I doing wrong? If I add a html file to the `src/main/webapp/index.html` it shows up for some reason only the rest api can't be reached.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic question, but was there any particular reason you decided to not use the embedded servlet with Spring Boot?

You might need to configure Tomcat's `web.xml` (servlet/servlet mapping)

Comment: Hey @TimTong thanks for the reply I am not sure what you mean by not use the embedded servlet can you elaborate? thanks

Comment: So you have two flavors or ways of deploying your application. Option 1: You can run an external Tomcat that accepts a WAR (this is the more traditional approach before spring boot). Option 2: You can run a JAR that contains the servlet (Tomcat) embedded inside. This is the more typical approach now with Spring boot.

Comment: Ah yes I need to use an existing tomcat setup on a remote server so i want mimic it locally

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot applications come with a built in Servlet. You are probably already using this feature when launching the application inside your IDE.

This basically means that you can just run your .jar file on any web server and it will be ready to go without setting up an extra tomcat instance.

However, if you want to build a Spring Boot application as a war file and deploy it to an external tomcat, you need to follow some extra steps as explained in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy).

Comment: I have seen this article before and followed to the steps in it but it still gives me the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from what you posted so far: the path that is returned shows another route before your actual controller route "/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello" is this "/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" the path that your application runs on ? If not it should be included in your controller (assuming you havent set it elsewhere for e.g. in your application.properties).
for e.g. http://localhost:8080/ would be the basepath and either http://localhost:8080/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello or http://localhost:8080/hello would point to your controller. Also your startup logs (for Tomcat and Spring) might give away more about the issue.